# Can you go to a shul dinner if you are in aveilus?

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, parties-celebrations

Can you go to a shul dinner or other formal function that is for social convention and not actually enjoyable if you are in aveilus?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66666

Answer (score 7):

From "[The Jewish Way in Death and Mourning](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281640/jewish/Joyous-Occasions-During-Mourning.htm)" by Maurice Lamm:

> Community business meetings, such as synagogue or fraternal
>   organization membership meetings, are permitted the mourner after
>   shiva.
>
> Social dinners, even though no music is played, and even though they
>   are held for charitable causes, are not to be attended by mourners for
>   parents for 12 months, and other mourners for 30 days.

I would advise reading the [entire](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281640/jewish/Joyous-Occasions-During-Mourning.htm) chapter, and obviously [CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) for practical guidance.

Comment: http://en.tvunah.org/2013/12/17/avel-attending-kollel-dinner/